# How to do "GROUP BY" in Redis

Tags: lua, redis

I'm try to find a solution, of how to get all the fields from a `HASH` that has the same values.

For example

```
redis > HSET my_hash "foo" 1
(integer) 1
redis > HSET my_hash "bar" 1
(integer) 1
redis > HSET my_hash "baz" 0
(integer) 1
redis > HGETALL my_hash
1) "foo"
2) "1"
3) "bar"
4) "1"
5) "baz"
6) "0"
```

So what I want is to do something like `HGETALL my_hash "WHERE VALUE = 1"`. And expected result would be `foo` and `bar`.
If someone could point me on how to do this using native commands or using `Lua` would be awesome.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like `HSCAN` should make it, but cannot find the exact way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this

in a lua script named script.lua

```
local hash_val = redis.call('hgetall',KEYS[1])
local result = {}
for i = 0 , #hash_val do
    if hash_val[i] == ARGV[1] then
        table.insert(result,hash_val[i-1])
        table.insert(result,hash_val[i])
    end
end
return result
```

lua get hash by sequence  key0,val0,key1,val1, etc...

and after you can call it that's way:

```
redis-cli  eval "$(cat script.lua)" 1 "my_hash" 1
```

you will have :

```
1) "foo"
2) "1"
3) "bar"
4) "1"
```

more information for the eval function [here](http://redis.io/commands/eval)

**edit :** as said deltheil in comment , for check only the values and don't make unecessary check you can step the for loop by 2 because the rendering of a hash request is key,values,key,value,etc...:

```
local hash_val = redis.call('hgetall',KEYS[1])
local result = {}
for i = 2 , #hash_val, 2 do
    if hash_val[i] == ARGV[1] then
        table.insert(result,hash_val[i-1])
        table.insert(result,hash_val[i])
    end
end
return result
```

Comment: Since you only want to check against values, the `for` loop should be `for i = 2, #hash_val, 2 do`.

Comment: you right  and we could probably increase checking by taking care of the key syntax also . but for starting and for this need , that's do the job

Comment: i had it, that's usefull for understanding