# Search and group products by shops REDIS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, key-value, key-value-store

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522511/how-to-do-group-by-in-redis) about Group By in redis but actually does not solve my issue. I have a complex search of products, once I got the ones I am looking for I want to group them by their shops, because they must be showed in a map.

My actual implementation is as follow:

-A function which search products by a pattern, it return products ids as "product:id"

```
product_ids = search_products_by_indexing(pattern)
```

-A hash with name "selling" which contains product:id/shop:id as key/value.

```
shops = $redis.hmget("selling", *product_ids)
# this returns list of shops as "shop:id" which sell the given prodcuts
```

-Then I do an intersection of shops with another list to get only shops located in a given city.

```
result_shops = shops & $redis.smembers("shops:city_name")
# OR by redis
$zinterstore(tem_id, shops, $redis.smembers("shops:city_name"))
result_shops = $redis.zrange(temp_id, 0, -1)
```

-The only thing I still need is to get the searched products grouped by result_shops. or for example this could be a hash as shop:id/[product:id] as key/value (this is the final result, shop must be in the city and product match the pattern)

Is my solution suitable to this problem or maybe there is a better implementation to solve it? any suggestion will be very appreciated!!

UPDATE: One product belongs to only one shop and one shop can have many products.

Answer (score 1):

> -A hash with name "selling" which contains product:id/shop:id as key/value.

This usage of a Hash will only allow you to one `shop:id` per `product:id`, meaning only one shop can sell a given product... perhaps the value should be a concatenated list of `shop:id`s or even better - use a Set `selling:product:id` and store all your relevant `shop:id`s in it.

> -Then I do an intersection of shops with another list to get only shops located in a given city.

IMO this is redundant as the intersect's results is always `shops:city_name`

> -The only thing I still need is to get the searched products grouped by result_shops.

If you've taken my Set instead of a Hash suggestion, this can be done with:

```
ZINTERSTORE tem_id 2 shops:city_name selling:product:id
ZRANGE tem_id 0 -1
```

Comment: thanks Itamar for your answer and time, but your solution actually returns only a list of shops (still need searched products of each shop in the result)
Anyway I forgot to mention that one product can be sold by only one shop, I update it in my post. Note: My reason in using hmget, because it can actually return many values of a given list of keys as argument. Probably this must be implemented other way?